# Is the difference between two iid log-concave distributions still log-concave?

Tags: probability, distributions, convex

Assume two iid random variables X and Y, with continuous and differentiable pdf $f$ and cdf $F$. Let Z=X-Y. Is the pdf of Z log-concave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of the difference $Z=X-Y$ is
$$g(z)=\int f(x)f(z+x)\text{d}x$$Then
\begin{align*}
g(\alpha z+(1-\alpha) w) &= \int f(x)f(\alpha z+(1-\alpha) w+x)\text{d}x\\&= \int f(x)f(\alpha (z+x)+(1-\alpha) (w+x))\text{d}x\\&= \int f(x)\exp\{\ln f(\alpha z+(1-\alpha) w+x)\}\text{d}x\\&\le\int f(x)\exp\{\alpha\ln f(z+x)+(1-\alpha)\ln f(w+x)\}\text{d}x\quad\text{[log-concavity of $f$]}\\&=\int \exp\{\alpha[\ln f(x)+\ln f(z+x)]+(1-\alpha)[\ln f(x)+\ln f(w+x)]\}\text{d}x\\&=\int \exp\{\ln f(x)+\ln f(z+x)]\}^\alpha\,\exp\{[\ln f(x)+\ln f(w+x)]\}^ {(1-\alpha)}\text{d}x\\&\le\left(\int \exp\{\ln f(x)+\ln f(z+x)]\}\text{d}x\right)^ {\alpha}\\
&\qquad\times\left(\int\exp\{[\ln f(x)+\ln f(w+x)]\}\text{d}x\right)^ {(1-\alpha)}\qquad\text{[Hölder's inequality]}
\end{align*}
and
$$\ln g(\alpha z+(1-\alpha) w) \le \alpha \ln g(z) + (1-\alpha) \ln g(w)$$